# dockerfile CMD executable and command

Tags: linux, docker

in part of docker document,

---

CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred form)

CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)

---

what is **executable**, **command** meaning?

I have confused about that.

What I think is `ll, cd, ls, chmod, cp`.

They are all  executable and command.

Because I try this in dockerfile

`CMD ["ll", "-a"]`

It's doesn't work.

But when we type ll in teminal, it's work, I think it's just execute `ll`.

I think I had some wrong concept about that.

Comment: I don't think `ll` is a standard command.  Do you mean `ls -al`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## CMD

### Usage:

1. CMD `["<executable>","<param1>","<param2>"]` (exec form, this is the preferred form)

From the docs

> - Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command shell. This means that *normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example*, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
>   $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or
>   execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"
>   ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the
>   case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment
>   variable expansion, not docker.
> - If you want to run your `<command>` without a shell then you must express the command as a JSON array and give the *full path to the
>   executable*. This array form is the preferred format of CMD. Any
>   additional parameters must be individually expressed as strings in the
>   array:

2. CMD `["<param1>","<param2>"]` (as default parameters to ENTRYPOINT)
3. CMD `<command> <param1> <param2>` (shell form)

> If you use the shell form of the CMD, then this  will execute
> in `/bin/sh -c`:

#### Coming to your problem

##### Exec Way

if you want to execute `ll` command using `executable way` then you would have two options available

- Add "sh" as first param like `CMD ["sh", "-c", "ll", "-a"]`.
- Or provide absolute path of `ll`(It is alias to `ls -lh`) executable like `CMD [ "/bin/ls", "-lh" "-a"]`

##### Shell way

if you want to execute `ll` command using `shell way` then you can use like this `CMD ll`

### References :

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd